# In SQL how do you find a row matching one condition, take a value from it and match it to other rows in the same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

For example if you had a table `books` and you wanted to find all books by a certain name, then get the author of those books and research the `books` table for all entries in the table. For instance if you searched the title "All About Pirates" and then there were 2 books with the title, one by "Jane Doe" and another by "Joe Smith" then the table would be searched again for all titles by those authors.

```
select *
from books b
join books b2 on b.author = b2.author
where title = 'All About Pirates'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sub query like this:
SELECT * FROM books WHERE author IN (SELECT author FROM books WHERE title='All About Pirates');

Answer (score 2):

Your query is almost correct.  You need to specify the alias for title in the where clause:

```
select b2.*
from books b join
     books b2
     on b.author = b2.author
where b.title = 'All About Pirates'
```

The original query was not parsable because the title was ambiguous.  In this query `b2` is the list of books with matching authors.

Answer (score 1):

You can join a table to the results of a select.

For example, you get the author(s) matching the book like this:

```
SELECT author FROM books WHERE title="All About Pirates" GROUP BY author;
```

So you can join the books table to this table of authors like this:

```
SELECT books.*
FROM books
JOIN (SELECT author FROM books WHERE title="All About Pirates" GROUP BY author) AS r
ON books.author=r.author;
```